# snappyHexMesh not meshing correct region

Tags: mesh-generation, openfoam, paraview

I created a simple model of cylindrical container to perform heat transfer simulation using FreeCAD for CAD modelling. I exported the model in stl format along with domain boundaries and faces. I have attached all the files here.

I have been trying to mesh the container domain. I am using cyclic blockMesh first to create a hex cylindrical block. Next I am using surfaceFeatures and snappyHexMesh to mesh the region inside the cylindrical container. To generate mesh in correct region I located a point using paraview that was clearly within the region where I want the mesh.

However, when I check the mesh in paraview, the mesh is generated for wrong region.
I tried different point locations but the result turns out to be the same.
I have attached the outputs of snappy and blockmesh as well.

Could someone help me understand why am I having this problem and how to solve it. Is it a bug in snappyHexMesh?

Thank you.

Here is the link to the files: [Container_Simulation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i0ohwjo0vt0fpci/consim.zip?dl=0)

[image: The snappyHexMesh result]

Comment: This is a question better suited to the user forums of the snappyHexMesh software itself.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth do you know any forum for snappyHexMesh? Please let me know if there is one. Thanks.

Comment: If I were you, I'd start with meshing a 1D line. If that works, I'd try a 2D square, then a qube, then a ball. That way debugging your problem becomes a lot easier and you may inspect your .stl file with the naked eye for correctness. Going slow is faster with these types of things.